# ImageMagick Conversion from svg to png/jpg results in distorted image

Tags: imagemagick

Somehow the Convert routine screws up my graphics... It used to work before. Does anyone have a clue what might have gone wrong (I installed the latest version of ImageMagick 7.0.5-10 and imagick 3.4.3, image converted through commandline)

**The input SVG**

http://defreule.info/scale.svg

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 35.55 35.72"><defs><style>.a{fill:#706f6f;}</style></defs><title>youtube</title><path class="a" d="M17.61,15.42a0.44,0.44,0,0,0,.31-0.11A0.39,0.39,0,0,0,18,15V12.43a0.31,0.31,0,0,0-.12-0.25,0.48,0.48,0,0,0-.31-0.1,0.43,0.43,0,0,0-.29.1,0.32,0.32,0,0,0-.11.25V15a0.41,0.41,0,0,0,.1.3A0.38,0.38,0,0,0,17.61,15.42Z"/><path class="a" d="M19.75,20.2a0.85,0.85,0,0,0-.4.1,1.38,1.38,0,0,0-.37.3V18.72H18.11v5.84H19V24.22a1.1,1.1,0,0,0,.37.29,1,1,0,0,0,.45.09,0.71,0.71,0,0,0,.58-0.24,1.07,1.07,0,0,0,.2-0.7V21.28a1.29,1.29,0,0,0-.21-0.81A0.74,0.74,0,0,0,19.75,20.2Zm0,3.35a0.47,0.47,0,0,1-.07.3,0.28,0.28,0,0,1-.23.09,0.48,0.48,0,0,1-.21,0,0.73,0.73,0,0,1-.2-0.15V21.05a0.64,0.64,0,0,1,.18-0.13,0.45,0.45,0,0,1,.18,0,0.33,0.33,0,0,1,.27.11,0.51,0.51,0,0,1,.09.33v2.22Z"/><polygon class="a" points="11.65 19.57 12.65 19.57 12.65 24.55 13.62 24.55 13.62 19.57 14.63 19.57 14.63 18.72 11.65 18.72 11.65 19.57"/><path class="a" d="M16.6,23.52a1.22,1.22,0,0,1-.27.23,0.49,0.49,0,0,1-.24.09,0.21,0.21,0,0,1-.18-0.07,0.37,0.37,0,0,1-.05-0.22v-3.3H15v3.6a0.92,0.92,0,0,0,.15.58,0.53,0.53,0,0,0,.45.19,1,1,0,0,0,.5-0.14,1.85,1.85,0,0,0,.5-0.4v0.47h0.86V20.25H16.6v3.27Z"/><path class="a" d="M17.76,1a17,17,0,1,0,17,17A17,17,0,0,0,17.76,1Zm2.05,10.38h1V15a0.39,0.39,0,0,0,.06.24,0.23,0.23,0,0,0,.2.08,0.56,0.56,0,0,0,.27-0.1A1.35,1.35,0,0,0,21.6,15v-3.6h1v4.74h-1V15.6A2,2,0,0,1,21,16a1.23,1.23,0,0,1-.56.15A0.61,0.61,0,0,1,20,16a1,1,0,0,1-.17-0.63v-4Zm-3.6,1.08a1.08,1.08,0,0,1,.39-0.88,1.59,1.59,0,0,1,1.05-.33,1.43,1.43,0,0,1,1,.34,1.14,1.14,0,0,1,.38.89v2.45a1.24,1.24,0,0,1-.37,1,1.48,1.48,0,0,1-1,.35,1.43,1.43,0,0,1-1-.36,1.26,1.26,0,0,1-.38-1V12.47ZM13.57,9.7l0.71,2.57h0.07L15,9.7h1.11l-1.27,3.76v2.67H13.77V13.58L12.47,9.7h1.1ZM26.26,23.23a3.11,3.11,0,0,1-3.11,3.11H12.36a3.11,3.11,0,0,1-3.11-3.11v-2.5a3.11,3.11,0,0,1,3.11-3.11h10.8a3.11,3.11,0,0,1,3.11,3.11v2.5Z"/><path class="a" d="M22.34,20.14a1.3,1.3,0,0,0-.94.35,1.21,1.21,0,0,0-.37.91v1.93a1.37,1.37,0,0,0,.33,1,1.18,1.18,0,0,0,.91.36,1.28,1.28,0,0,0,1-.33,1.38,1.38,0,0,0,.32-1V23.12H22.68v0.2a0.94,0.94,0,0,1-.09.49,0.36,0.36,0,0,1-.3.11A0.32,0.32,0,0,1,22,23.79a1,1,0,0,1-.08-0.47V22.5h1.65v-1.1a1.29,1.29,0,0,0-.32-0.94A1.21,1.21,0,0,0,22.34,20.14Zm0.34,1.69H21.92V21.4A0.63,0.63,0,0,1,22,21a0.34,0.34,0,0,1,.29-0.12,0.33,0.33,0,0,1,.29.12,0.64,0.64,0,0,1,.09.39v0.43Z"/></svg>
```

**Resulting Image**

`convert scale.svg test.png`

[image]

**Update**

It seems that when i use `file > save as` in Illustrator to save my .svg the converter does work fine. However when I use `file>export` the svg looks fine, but converting to png fails. I am still interested in why this is.

Comment: Can you tell us about the version installed, and command used to generate the file? Resulting image appears fine for me in both IM6 & IM7 without using rsvg.

Comment: `convert scale.svg test.png` is the command used. ImageMagick Version 7.0.5-10 and imagick version 3.4.3

Comment: What is bad about your result? Or post your output result.  Do you have either Inkscape or RSVG installed as a delegate? If not, ImageMagick will use its internal MSVG/XML SVG reader.  The other two are better.  Looking at your SVG file, IM says it is totally opaque, but has an alpha channel. But when I render it with SVG, I get a black circle where SVG shows transparent and a white background. So that is odd. The rendering with SVG seems to remove the transparent circle leaving a black circle. So the transparency is lost. You should specify -background somecolor before reading the SVG file.

Comment: CONTINUED: I get the same result using IM 7.0.5.10 and IM 6.9.8.9 Mac OSX with RSVG 2.40.16. The result is black circle with white lettering surrounded by white. The transparent circle I see when viewing with Mac Preview is not preserved.  When viewing with GraphicsConvert on the Mac, it shows as a gray circle with transparent letters and transparency outside the circle. So one of these viewers is wrong.  I think it is  IM with RSVG. Try using ImageMagick with Inkscape.

Comment: CONTINUED2: This command preserves the transparency of the outside of the circle and the letters, but makes the gray circle into black. magick -background none -density 300 scale.svg test.png